# Simple reverse proxy?

Tags: proxy

I want to build a reverse proxy. It needs to "rebroadcast" a specific SHOUTcast stream. I want to host this somewhere else.

- What's the cheapest way to do this? A cheap VPS?
- What's the simplest software solution for this? I have tried mitmproxy on my local machine but it doesn't seem to work:

```
mitmproxy -p 8010 -P http://[url]:8002
```

VLC fails...

```
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'http://localhost:8010/[stream]'.
```

And mitmproxy says:

```
>> GET http://[url]:8002/[stream]
   ← 502: Invalid server response.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best tool for this that I know of is [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/). An example of what you want would look like this:

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:8010,fork,reuseaddr TCP4:<server address>:8002
```

This would listen on port 8010 (on all interfaces) and then forward the traffic to *server address* on port 8002. Any responses would be forwarded back to the original sender.

Note that the *server address* should not contain the protocol or path but just the domain or IP address (e.g. www.google.com, **NOT** http://www.google.com/).

The **fork** parameter allows multiple connections and the **reuseaddr** keeps socat from needlessly tying up the address in case it crashes.

Comment: Wonderful, that's exactly the tool I needed.